# Angular разное поведение в различных шаблонах

Tags: angularjs, ng-repeat

Имеется шаблон, который выводится на разных страницах (под разными url). В шаблоне есть строка:

```
<li ng-repeat="user in vm.getLawyers()"><a ng-click="vm.TicketUserFilter(user)" href=""><ticket-lawyer-label lawyer="user"></ticket-lawyer-label></a></li>
```

есть проблемы с функцией vm.getLawyers(). Эта функция должна выводить список пользователй, отсортированных по группам. Вот js код, где происходит выборка пользователей:

```
$scope.$watch("vm.team.id", function(teamId) {
  return User.getList({
    profile__is_lawyer: "True",
    teams: teamId
  }).then(function(data) {
    vm.lawyers = data;
    return console.log(teamId);
  });
});
```

проблема в teams: teamId, на одних станицах данное условие выполняется, а на других teamId определяется как undefined и пользователи выводятся скопом, без выборки.
Может кто подскажет в чем может быть проблема, в какую сторону копать
В общем смотрите, функция vm.getLawyers() на coffee

```
vm.getLawyers = ->
    if vm.lawyers and vm.currentLawyer
        return (lawyer for lawyer in vm.lawyers when lawyer.id isnt vm.currentLawyer.id)
    else
        return vm.lawyers
```

a vm.lawyers получаем отсюда:

```
$scope.$watch "vm.team.id", (teamId) ->
    User.getList(profile__is_lawyer: "True", teams: teamId).then (data) ->
        vm.lawyers = data
```

роутер такой:

```
app = angular.module "adherents.routes", [ "niz.djangoStatic", "ngRoute" ]
# 
# === ROUTING ===
#
app.config ["$routeProvider", "djangoStatic", ($routeProvider, djangoStatic) ->
    $routeProvider
        .when "/adherent/:adherentId",
            templateUrl: djangoStatic "adherents/partials/wks-adherent.html" # это страница где не определяется team
            title: "adhérent"
            controller: "AdherentCtrl"
         ..................
         .................
        .when "/inbox",
            templateUrl: djangoStatic "adherents/partials/inbox.html" # это страница где определяется
            title: "boite de réception"
        .......................
        .......................
        .otherwise "/inbox"
]
# Set title based on route
app.run ["$rootScope", "$route", ($rootScope, $route) ->
    $rootScope.$on "$routeChangeSuccess", (currentRoute, previousRoute) ->
        $rootScope.title = $route.current.title
]
```

а контроллер AdherentCtrl такой:

```
# controller for the adherent (wks) page
app.controller "AdherentCtrl", ["$scope", "$routeParams", "ConversationViewer", "Adherent", "News", "Contact", "Search", "Restangular", ($scope, $routeParams, ConversationViewer, Adherent, News, Contact, Search, Restangular) ->
    adhId = $routeParams.adherentId

    $scope.ConversationViewer = ConversationViewer
    $scope.showEmail = ConversationViewer.show

    $scope.libraryFilter =
        from_adherent: adhId

    # no filter by team: wks adherent is global
    #$scope.$watch "main.currentTeam.id", (teamId) ->
    #    $scope.libraryFilter.team = teamId

    $scope.ticketFilter =
        adherent: adhId

    # no filter by team: wks adherent is global
    #$scope.$watch "main.currentTeam.id", (teamId) ->
    #    $scope.ticketFilter.team = teamId

    # bookmark or unbookmark the adherent
    $scope.toggleFavorite = ->
        method = if $scope.adherent.favorite then "unbookmark" else "bookmark"
        Adherent.one(adhId).all(method).post().then (data) ->
            $scope.adherent.favorite = data.favorite
            $scope.main.loadFavorites()


    # get the selected adherent data
    Adherent.get(adhId, log_access: "True").then (data) ->
        $scope.adherent = data
        $scope.main.loadLast() # reload last open wks adherent

    # get contacts
    Contact.getList(adherent: adhId).then (data) ->
        $scope.contacts = data

    # create a new contact
    $scope.newContact = ->
        contact =
            adherent_id: $scope.adherent.id

        Restangular.restangularizeElement(null, contact, "contact")
        $scope.contacts.push contact

    # function to save a contact and update ID
    $scope.saveContact = (contact) ->
        contact.save().then (data) ->
            Restangular.copy(data, contact)

    # find contacts for import
    $scope.findContacts = (query) ->
        Contact.getList(search: query, adherent_isnull: "True", limit:20)

    # add (import) a contact found by the typeahead
    $scope.addContact = ->
        contact = $scope.imported.contact
        contact.adherent_id = $scope.adherent.id
        $scope.saveContact contact
        $scope.contacts.push contact
        $scope.imported.contact = null


    # get + refresh news
    refreshNews = ->
        News.getList(adherent: adhId).then (data) ->
            $scope.news = data
    refreshNews()

    News.options().then (data) ->
        $scope.newsOptions = data

    # news form
    $scope.resetNewsForm = () ->
        $scope.newNews =
            adherent: adhId
            expires: null

    # manage news
    $scope.resetNewsForm()
    $scope.submitNewsForm = () ->
        postitem = angular.copy $scope.newNews
        if postitem.expires
            postitem.expires = postitem.expires.format "YYYY-MM-DD"
        News.post(postitem).then (data) ->
            refreshNews()

    # save the adherent data
    $scope.saveAdherent = ->
        adh = $scope.adherent
        adh.save()


    # execute search
    $scope.$watch "searchTerm", ->
        if $scope.searchTerm
            $scope.adhActTabs = 'aaT4'

]
```

Comment: во-первых, неправильное использование `$watch`, во-вторых - стоит почитать [справку по этой функции](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch), и что за параметры она передает в  коллбэк

Comment: как вообще функция _vm.getLawyers_ связана с установкой наблюдателя???

Comment: @Grundy Код составлен на coffeescript и автоматом компилируется в js, поэтому я приведу как есть на самом деле. Функция vm.getLawyers() вот такая:

Comment: "            vm.getLawyers = ->
                if vm.lawyers and vm.currentLawyer
                    return (lawyer for lawyer in vm.lawyers when lawyer.id isnt vm.currentLawyer.id)
                else
                    return vm.lawyers"

Comment: Все необходимое добавляй прямо в вопрос, а не в комментарии

Comment: где устанавливается  `vm.team.id`?

Comment: @Grundy vm = this , а team нам передается по restapi. На одной странице team хорошо видна, можно вывести его в шаблон или в консоль, а на другой странице team не определяется undefined

Comment: добавляй определения этих страниц в вопрос, и, возможно, настройки роутера если используется

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50231/discussion-between-grundy-and-ihar).

Comment: @Grundy я написал в чате, посмотрите пожалуйста